# img tag center align in div tag horizontal

Tags: html, css

```
<section class="bg-light ">
        <div class="output-container ">
            <img id="output-img " src="img/styles/cry.jpg " height=256></img>
        </div>
</section>
```

//I tried img tag id "output-img" center aligned horizontally in div tag class name "output-container" . 
And this is my css codes.

```
.output-container{
    text-align: center;
}
#outputImg{
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

I removed display: block in #outputImg, but also didn't work. 
I applied some codes in stackoverflow but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong on this, but as far as I know the name of the id must be the same in both the css and html.

```
<img id="output-img">
```

Keeping the same syntax in the css as well...

```
#output-img {
  code stuff here
}
```

This is instead of "output-img" and "outputImg".

Hopefully that makes some sort of sense.

Comment: It was my mistake to attach wrong codes in this question page.
unfortunately It didn't work. 
however, Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

It's working here in Chrome and I included the standard bootstrap css file so I don't think that the code you've included is your issue.

There are some typos here:

- you should have quotes around the value of the `height` attribute
- the `img` tag doesn't use a closing tag
- the `#output-img` css rule should match the id.

If using valid code doesn't do the trick, try setting the `display` property of the image to `table`.

```css
.output-container {
  text-align: center;
}

#output-img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="bg-light ">
  <div class="output-container ">
    <img id="output-img " src="https://via.placeholder.com/256" height="256">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: weird,.... I checked the snippet you attached worked find... 
but can't get why my page didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `text-align:center;` and replace it with `place-items:end center;`. Text-align is actually meant to be used with (you guessed it) text. [`place-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items) is used to align (or place) non text items inside their respective containers. Using `place-items: end center;` positions the item (in this case, the image) in the center from the end and keeps it from getting stuck at the start (or left side) of the container.

CSS changes:

```
.output-container{
    place-items: end center;
}

#output-img {
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

HTML changes include removing the closing `</img>` tag and (all) additional spaces in the values `" "`. (Both items mentioned in other answers.)

```
<section class="bg-light">
        <div class="output-container">
            <img id="output-img" src="img/styles/cry.jpg" height="256">
        </div>
</section>
```

---

Appended:

---

I added a sample image for demonstration purposes. This works in my (Chrome) browser, test it again. If it's still not working - this might be a browser issue. CSS is commonplace and I would think that all browsers recognize it, but not all browsers use the most current version of CSS. Logically, that could be the problem.

```css
.output-container{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    place-items: end center;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

#output-img {
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-light">
        <div class="output-container">
            <img id="output-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYMbc.gif" height="100%">
        </div>
</section>
```

---

[image: sample image for testing purposes]

Comment: but really appreciate your comments!

Comment: I'm beginning to think this could be an issue with the broswer you are using. Please run the code snippet I added to test my theory.